# lmer failing even with no NAs in dataframe

Tags: r, lme4

When I run lmer with fixed and random effects, I get the following error:

> Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) : NA/NaN/Inf in
> foreign function call (arg 1)

However I have already tested every column in my dataframe to make sure there aren't NAs before analysis. I have also added in `na.action = na.omit` just in case with no success.

I'm not proficient at R to the point where I feel comfortable using the `debug()` function, but I've seen some people suggest that in other posts. I did `traceback()` but honestly not sure what I'm looking for there, I'll provide the output below though in case that is helpful.

I have one response variable, two fixed effects, and one random effect.

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  seal_ID  diveNum D_phase datetime                      Depth    MSA rate_s    HR
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <dttm>                        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Congaree       1 D       2018-04-06 14:47:40            4.76 0.246   0     117. 
2 Congaree       1 D       2018-04-06 14:48:00            5.06 0.232   0.865 100. 
3 Congaree       1 D       2018-04-06 14:48:20            5.78 0.227   0      49.7
4 Congaree       1 B       2018-04-06 14:48:40            8.5  0.0629  0      40.3
5 Congaree       1 D       2018-04-06 14:48:40            7.29 0.159   0      39.9
6 Congaree       1 DB      2018-04-06 14:48:40            7.5  0.538   0      42.0

#In my model I want to know how rate_s and Depth affect HR with seal_ID as random effect
> model<-lmer(HR ~ rate_s*Depth +(1|seal_ID), data = df, na.action = na.omit)
Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

#The results of my traceback()
> traceback()
11: qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE)
10: qr(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE)
9: chkRank.drop.cols(X, kind = rankX.chk, tol = 1e-07)
8: lme4::lFormula(formula = HR ~ rate_s * Depth + 
       (1 | seal_ID), data = df, control = structure(list(
       optimizer = "nloptwrap", restart_edge = TRUE, boundary.tol = 1e-05, 
       calc.derivs = TRUE, use.last.params = FALSE, checkControl = list(
           check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore", check.nobs.vs.nlev = "stop", 
           check.nlev.gtreq.5 = "ignore", check.nlev.gtr.1 = "stop", 
           check.nobs.vs.nRE = "stop", check.rankX = "message+drop.cols", 
           check.scaleX = "warning", check.formula.LHS = "stop"), 
       checkConv = list(check.conv.grad = list(action = "warning", 
           tol = 0.002, relTol = NULL), check.conv.singular = list(
           action = "message", tol = 1e-04), check.conv.hess = list(
           action = "warning", tol = 1e-06)), optCtrl = list()), class = c("lmerControl", 
   "merControl")))
7: eval(mc, parent.frame(1L))
6: eval(mc, parent.frame(1L))
5: lme4::lmer(formula = HR ~ rate_s * Depth + 
       (1 | seal_ID), data = df)
4: eval(expr, p)
3: eval(expr, p)
2: eval.parent(mc)
1: lmer(HR ~ rate_s * Depth + (1 | seal_ID), 
       data = df)
```

Comment: Are any fields factor? e.g. is.factor(df$seal_ID)

Comment: @Skaqqs yes, seal_ID is categorical and the others are numeric. I tried running is.factor(df$seal_ID) first before running lmer, but I still get the same error message from lmer.

Comment: Provide an example dataste using `dput(x)`.

Comment: Please post enough data for us to replicate your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite surprising. You can avoid the particular step that's failing by using `control = lmerControl(check.rankX = "ignore"))` in your `lmer()` call, but I suspect you will run into trouble farther along the line.

The failure is occurring at the step where `lmer` tries to check to see whether any sets of columns are multicollinear.  The part that's failing can recapitulated more simply as:

```r
X <- model.matrix( ~ rate_s * Depth, data = df)
qr1 <- qr(X, tol = 1e-7, LAPACK = FALSE)
```

Does this fail in the same way?  What is `summary(X)`? `nrow(X)` ?